# ACRA mailto option not including user comment field

Tags: android, acra

Configured for mail and getting mail, but the user comment in the dialog is not added to the mail text, my acra config looks like this

```
    @ReportsCrashes(formKey="dGVacG0ydVHnaNHjRjVTUTEtb3FPWGc6MQ",
mode = ReportingInteractionMode.DIALOG,
mailTo = "bugmail_me_xyz@gmail.com",
customReportContent = { ReportField.APP_VERSION_CODE, ReportField.APP_VERSION_NAME,
        ReportField.ANDROID_VERSION, ReportField.PHONE_MODEL, ReportField.CUSTOM_DATA,
        ReportField.STACK_TRACE, ReportField.LOGCAT },                

//resToastText = R.string.crash_toast_text, // optional, displayed as soon as the crash occurs, before collecting data which can take a few seconds
resDialogText = R.string.crash_dialog_text,
resDialogIcon = android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_info, //optional. default is a warning sign
resDialogTitle = R.string.crash_dialog_title, // optional. default is your application name
resDialogCommentPrompt = R.string.crash_dialog_comment_prompt, // optional. when defined, adds a user text field input with this text resource as a label
resDialogOkToast = R.string.crash_dialog_ok_toast // optional. displays a Toast message when the user accepts to send a report.
)
```

Comment: Did my answer solved your problem? just curious about it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing this field in customReportContent:

```
    ReportField.USER_COMMENT
```

You can check all the fields you can use in [here](https://github.com/ACRA/acra/wiki/ReportContent).

Comment: Hi, I have the same problem as the OP. When I add the USER_COMMENT, it's returning null. Did you encounter this issue?